# how to share a url with # in twitter using tweet_button.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

**i have a twitter img with onclick function tweetpage**

`<img src="images/twtr.png" onclick="tweetPage();"/>`

```
function tweetPage()
{
  var url = "http://www.website.com/index.html#eyJkIjoidGhpcyBpcyBh";
  var testUrl ="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url="+url
  var htmlStr = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"'
              +'src="'+testUrl+'"'
              +'style="width:130px; height:20px;padding-top: 37%;"></iframe>'
  $('#twitLindDiv').html(htmlStr);
}
```

**and a tweetbutton is shown. clicking on the tweet button a twitter popup box is shown
but the url in textbox contains only**

> http://www.website.com/index.html

**how can i solve this.**

**I also tried**

> &hashtags=   instead of #

**the result was**

> http://www.website.com/index.html #eyJkIjoidGhpcyBpcyBh

**how can i solve this**

---

Answer (score 2):

> tweetid   is the div to which this inner html is added (this works fine for me.)

```
var referenceUrl = window.location.toString();
var shareUrl = 'http://www.website.com/index.html#eyJkIjoidGhpcyBpcyBh'
$('#tweetid').html('<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1368146021.html#_=1369640770351&amp;
count=none&amp;
id=twitter-widget-0&amp;
lang=en&amp;original_referer='
+encodeURIComponent(referenceUrl)
+'&amp;related=nothing%20to%20worry&amp;size=m&amp;
text=LiveImpact&amp;
url='+encodeURIComponent(shareUrl)
+'" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-none" title="Twitter Tweet Button" data-twttr-rendered="true" style="width: 56px; height: 20px;">'
+'</iframe>');
```